# Create new 2d array of the argmax from two 2d np.arrays element-wise

Tags: python, numpy, numpy-ndarray, argmax

Say I have, as an arbitrary example, two 2d numpy arrays, X and Y where

```
    X = np.array([[0,1,2,3],
                  [4,5,6,7]]) 
    Y = np.array([[1,2,3,4],
                  [1,1,7,3]])
```

I want to create a new 2d numpy array, Z, that is the argmax of X,Y element-wise so Z would be, in this example:

```
    Z = np.array([[1,2,3,4],
                  [4,5,7,7]])
```

I've tried variations of the following none return the intended result

```
    np.array([(np.argmax(X,Y))]) --> error
```

I know I can do this simply by using a nested for loop but that isn't very efficient for very large datasets. Is there an efficient, numpy-specific, way to create a new 2d array (Z, in the example above) composed of the argmax by element from two 2d arrays (X and Y, in the example above)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're looking for [`np.maximum`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.maximum.html):

```
>>> np.maximum(X, Y)

array([[1, 2, 3, 4],
       [4, 5, 7, 7]])
```

which compares the arrays element-wise and returns the maximum for each of them.

Comment: Thank you! This is very helpful to know.

Answer (score 1):

Use [`numpy.where`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.where.html):

```
Z = np.where(X > Y, X, Y)
```

Here, the first argument `X > Y` compares `X` and `Y` element by element, and returns a boolean array of the comparison. Then we use the boolean array to build `Z`: if the element at an index is `True`, it uses the value from `X`, and if it is `False` it uses the value from `Y`.